# Automatic generation of integration points and weights for triangles and tetrahedra

Tags: symbolic-computation, reference-request

Usually one would consult a paper or book to find integration points and weights for unit triangle and tetrahedra. I am  looking for a method to automatically compute such points and weights. The following *Mathematica* code example computes integration weights and points for unit line (quad/hexahedron) elements:

```
unitGaussianQuadraturePoints[points_] := 
  Sort[x /. 
    Solve[Evaluate[LegendreP[points, x] == 0], {x}], ! 
     OrderedQ[N[{#1, #2}]] &];

unitGaussianQuadratureWeights[points_] := 
  Module[{gps, f, int, integr, vars, eqns}, 
   gps = unitGaussianQuadraturePoints[points];
   f[0, 0] := 1;
   f[0., 0] := 1.;
   f[x_, n_] := x^n;
   int = Integrate[f[x, #], x] & /@ Range[0, points - 1];
   integr = Subtract @@@ (int /. x :> {1, -1});
   vars = Table[Unique[c], {Length[gps]}];
   eqns = 
    Table[Plus @@ Thread[Times[vars, f[#, i - 1] & /@ gps]] == 
      integr[[i]], {i, points}];
   Return[(vars /. Solve[eqns, vars])];];


unitGaussianQuadratureWeights[2]

{{1, 1}}

unitGaussianQuadraturePoints[2]

{1/Sqrt[3], -(1/Sqrt[3])}
```

I am looking for a paper/book that describes algorithmically how this is done for triangles and/or tetrahedra. Can someone point me to some information about this. Thanks.

Comment: There's an easier way to do your Gauss-Legendre quadrature rules in *Mathematica*: `{points, weights} = MapThread[Map, {{2 # - 1 &, 2 # &}, Most[NIntegrate\`GaussRuleData[n, prec]]}]`.

Comment: In any event: have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/838250.838253)?

Comment: @J.M, your above proposed method does, unfortunately, not work for prec=Infinity; but thanks for that too.

Comment: In that case, here's a method that works, due to Golub and Welsch: `Transpose[MapAt[2(First /@ #)^2 &, Eigensystem[SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> #, Band[{1, 2}] -> #}, {n, n}]], {2}]] &[Table[k/Sqrt[(2 k - 1)(2 k + 1)], {k, n - 1}]]`.

Comment: @J.M., nice to know, since it is faster for higher n, do you perhaps happen to have an exact reference? However, I am more interested in something like this for triangles and tets. You don't happen to have something like this for those too? That would be fantastic.

Comment: [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-69-99647-1) is the paper by Golub and Welsch. I'll dig through my papers and see if there's something for simplices...

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/155743.155785) as well.

Comment: See also [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0715019), [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0045-7825(86)90059-9), and [SIMPACK](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/simpack/simpack.html).

Comment: For future reference, Alg. 824 mentions (among others) DCUTRI (Berntsen and Espelid [1990], Alg 706) and DCUTET (Berntsen et al. [1990,1993], Alg, 720) for triangles and tets.

Comment: For future reference, Alg. 706 and 720 mention only one high degree rule, at least I am not able to deduce a general algorithm from that.

Comment: The symbolic version of Eigensystem needs to be normalized, to give the same results as in a numerical case: `MapAt[2 (First /@ Normalize /@ #)^2 &, 
    Eigensystem[
     SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> #, Band[{1, 2}] -> #}, {n, 
       n}]], {2}] &[Table[k/Sqrt[(2 k - 1) (2 k + 1)], {k, n - 1}]];`

Answer (score 8):

The [Encyclopaedia of Cubature Formulas](http://nines.cs.kuleuven.be/ecf/) has an extensive list of techniques for this purpose and associated references.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a paper http://journal.library.iisc.ernet.in/vol200405/paper6/rathod.pdf that describes how to map the unit triangle to the standard 2-square in order to calculate the weights and sampling points for the triangle in terms of Gauss-Legendre points for the standard 2-square.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, it looks like for n=2 this needs 4 points, for the typical literature reference for triangles for n=2, 3 points are given. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: This stems from the fact that they are using a mapping from the triangle to the square. I can't say anything beyond that since I don't work with triangles (I use quadrilaterals), so I don't know what is usually done in practice. I just found the paper and thought it seemed like a pretty straightforward thing to do.

Comment: indeed it is quite straightforward and I'll see that the other papers suggest, but the simplicity for this one and the elegance of using something I already have are a plus for this one. The downside is then the additional function evaluation. Thanks in any case.

Comment: another down side is that the points are not symmetrical.